# Usando coordenadas do banco de dados no google maps API

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-maps-api-3

Estou tentando utilizar no Google Maps, os dados que estão em um banco de dados `sqlite`, mas não estou conseguindo acessar o retorno do loader.
Utilizei a mesma lógica para fazer ligação usando o número do banco de dados e funcionou, mas para o mapa, só retorna coordenada 0,0.
Segue o código, se alguém puder me ajudar onde estou errando, pois faz uma semana que estou travado nesse ponto.

```
public class MapsDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
private static final int EXISTING_DATA_LOADER = 0;
private Uri mCurrentUri;
double placeLat, placeLong;

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_detail);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mCurrentUri = intent.getData();
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(EXISTING_DATA_LOADER, null, this);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng place = new LatLng(placeLat, placeLong);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place));
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = {GuideContract.GuideEntry._ID,
            GuideContract.GuideEntry.COLUMN_PLACE_LATITUDE,
            GuideContract.GuideEntry.COLUMN_PLACE_LONGITUDE};
    return new CursorLoader(this,mCurrentUri, projection, null,null,null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int latColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(GuideContract.GuideEntry.COLUMN_PLACE_LATITUDE);
        int lonColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(GuideContract.GuideEntry.COLUMN_PLACE_LONGITUDE);

        int latitude = cursor.getInt(latColumnIndex);
        int longitude = cursor.getInt(lonColumnIndex);

        placeLat = latitude;
        placeLong = longitude;

    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Loader retorna os dados de forma assíncrona, então provalmente seu mapa inicializa antes do Loader retornar com os resultados. Tente inicializar o mapa dentro do método onLoadFinished() do Loader, após obter as coordenadas.

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigado!!!